# Will this template function correctly match a class with multiple bases?

Tags: c++

This code compiles and runs fine with clang, but gcc gives the compilation error:

> no matching function for call to ‘unpack(tag1, A3&)’

So is it valid c++?

```
#include <type_traits>                                                           
#include <utility>                                                               
#include <cassert>                                                                                                                                      

template <class Tag, class Value>                                                
class Pack                                                                       
{                                                                                
 public:                                                                         
  Pack(const Value& value) : _value(value) {}                                    
  Value value() const { return _value; }                                         
private:                                                                         
  Value _value;                                                                  
};                                                                                                                                                  

template<class Tag, class Value>                                                 
decltype(auto) unpack(Tag, Pack<Tag, Value>& pack) {                             
  return pack.value();                                                           
}                                                                                

struct tag1 {};                                                                  
struct tag2 {};                                                                  

struct A3 : Pack<tag1, int>, Pack<tag2, double> {                                
  A3(int x, double y) : Pack<tag1, int>(x), Pack<tag2, double>(y) {}             
};                                                                               

int main() {                                                                     
  A3 a3(1, 2);                                                                   
  assert(unpack(tag1(), a3) == 1);                                               
  assert(unpack(tag2(), a3) == 2);                                               
}
```

Comment: "valid" in this context mean two things -- syntantically correct or good design. Which one do you mean?

Comment: syntactically correct

Comment: @RSahu: I disagree. "Valid" in this context can only mean syntactically correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Tag` is in a deduced context for each of the function parameters (`Tag` and `Pack<Tag, Value> &`). Template argument deduction is performed independently for each and the result must match. When attempting to deduce `Pack<Tag, Value>` from `A3`, two possible deductions are possible, so type deduction fails.

Simplest fix is probably getting rid of the tag function parameter and instead just call `unpack` with an explicit template argument - `unpack<tag1>(a3)` is not more verbose than `unpack(tag1(), a3)`. If you still prefer the original syntax, a forwarder can be written:

```
template<class Tag, class SomePack>
decltype(auto) unpack(Tag, SomePack& pack) { return unpack<Tag>(SomePack); }
```

Comment: The version with nondeduced still gives the same error with gcc (4.9.2)

Comment: Was the version with nondeduced legal (just a gcc bug)?

Comment: @rnickb On second thought, I'm doubtful. For it to work would require a deduce-substitute-deduce again procedure, which I don't think the standard specifies.

Answer (score 0):

It is not only a problem with multiple inheritance. It is also a problem with template instantation.

The expression `unpack(tag1(), a3)` matches to a call of a function with the signature `unpack(tag1, Pack<tag1, A3> &)` and the `return pack.value()` is ambiguous when pack is of type `Pack<tag1, A3>`.

That means the compiler (assuming C++14) of `decltype(auto)` will fail.

Comment: Why would it match unpack(tag1, Pack<tag1, A3>&)? with clang the first assertion matches unpack(tag1, Pack<tag1, int>&) and I don't see any ambiguity with deducing the return type from decltype(auto) in that context

Comment: That's because you're thinking in terms of what would happen if the template was already instantiated.   The ambiguity is in instantiating the template - which is a separate process that has to be resolved before your logic would apply.